# How to bind same key for two different treeviewers present under same context Id and SchemeId

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, key-bindings

I have two treeviewers in same view and I want to bind "Delete" key to both of them.If both keys are not same then it is working fine,the problem arises when I bind same key to both the treeviewer.Both of the them have same schemeId and contextId.Can you suggest some thing on this?

Comment: TreeViewers don't have a schemeId or contextId so I don't understand what you are asking. A key binding binds a key to a command - what command are you using?

Comment: I meant to say both of the treeviewer is created under the same view.I want to associate delete key to both of the trees.The commands are different for both of the delete.

Comment: So why are there two commands? You can only bind a key to a single command in a context.

Comment: Ok,Is there any workaround how we can achieve this having same context  .Will creating a different scheme help?

Comment: You haven't explained why you have two commands. Write one command and handler that deals with both trees and bind delete to that.

Comment: Seems like a good idea.I will try this.

Comment: Thanks Greg.That solved my problem. :)